# How do you prevent jQuery code executing on a mobile device?

Tags: jquery, mobile, responsive-design

I'm currently working on building a site with a responsive design. As part of that I need to prevent the below code from executing if the user visits the website using a mobile device. How can I achieve that?

The code:

```
var leftHeight = $("#sidebar").height();
var rightHeight = $("#main").height();
if (leftHeight > rightHeight){ $("#main").height(leftHeight)}
else{ $("#sidebar").height(rightHeight+25)};

function equalHeight() {
    var heightArray = $("#footer>div.box").map(function () {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get();

    var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heightArray);
    $("#footer>div.box").height(maxHeight);
}
equalHeight();
```

Comment: How are you determining if the user is on a mobile device?

Comment: So you want to not execute that entire block of code if they're on a mobile device?

Comment: @Anthony Grist thats right!

Comment: Are you sure you want to prevent the code from running on mobile devices or do you want to prevent the code from running for a certain view size? (I assume you you use media queries to have different layouts and for a certain layout this script should not run?)

Comment: t.niese, i use the media queries, yes. When the window is smaller then 980px the functions must not work anymore.

Comment: @Maanstraat, but what if i change the window to a size smaller then `980px` on my desktop or laptop. Would the script then behave correctly ?

Answer (score -1):

I think i have found a solution:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 980 ) {
    $("#sidebar").height("auto");
    $("#footer .box").height("auto");
}
```

Comment: How gave this a **-1** and why? I know the Question is about  detection mobile device. But depending on the requirement this is the right solution, instead of testing for the mobil device.

Comment: If you write an answer you should explain what you did and why, especially if your answer (solution) does not exactly match the question (even if it is yours).